# why is coverage being ignored by sonar?

Tags: python, sonarqube

I don't understand what is happening with my multimodule project in python (only an experiment with sonar).
This is the sonar log (not complete):

```
    .
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1 test in 0.000s

    OK
    Name                   Stmts   Miss  Cover
    ------------------------------------------
    calculator                 5      1    80%
    test/__init__              1      0   100%
    test/test_calculator       8      0   100%
    ------------------------------------------
    TOTAL                     14      1    93%
    My Other Calculator
    ===================================

    mkdir: cannot create directory `../coverage-reports': File exists
    .
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1 test in 0.000s

    OK
    Name                    Stmts   Miss  Cover
    -------------------------------------------
    calculator2                 3      0   100%
    test/__init__               1      0   100%
    test/test_calculator2       8      0   100%
    -------------------------------------------
    TOTAL                      12      0   100%

    Executing sonar-runner....

    Sonar Runner 2.2
    Java 1.7.0_09-icedtea Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
    Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 amd64
    INFO: Runner configuration file: /home/jenkins/tools/sonar/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
    INFO: Project configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Servidor-RDS/workspace/serv/rdsweb/WebContent/fccma/js/fcc/tests/python-sonar-runner/sonar-project.properties
    INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
    INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Servidor-RDS/workspace/serv/rdsweb/WebContent/fccma/js/fcc/tests/python-sonar-runner/.sonar
    INFO: Sonar Server 3.5.1
    ...
    17:07:06.947 INFO  - -------------  Inspecting myCalculator
    17:07:06.954 INFO  - Load module settings
    17:07:07.376 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=py]
    17:07:07.405 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
    ....
    17:07:09.347 INFO  - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor...
    17:07:09.348 INFO  - Parsing report '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Servidor-RDS/workspace/serv/rdsweb/WebContent/fccma/js/fcc/tests/python-sonar-runner/myCalculator/coverage-reports/coverage_myCalculator.xml'
    ....
    17:07:10.313 INFO  - Execute decorators...
    17:07:11.033 INFO  - -------------  Inspecting myOtherCalculator
    17:07:11.034 INFO  - Load module settings
    17:07:11.117 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=py]
    17:07:11.118 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
    ....
    17:07:12.618 INFO  - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor...
    17:07:12.619 INFO  - Parsing report '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Servidor-RDS/workspace/serv/rdsweb/WebContent/fccma/js/fcc/tests/python-sonar-runner/myOtherCalculator/coverage-reports/coverage_myOtherCalculator.xml'
   ....
    17:07:13.477 INFO  - -------------  Inspecting My calculator
    17:07:13.478 INFO  - Load module settings
    17:07:13.551 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=py]
    17:07:13.553 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
   ....
    17:07:13.654 INFO  - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor...
    17:07:13.654 INFO  - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor done: 0 ms
    ....
    17:07:13.943 INFO  - Execute decorators...
    17:07:14.098 INFO  - Persist graphs of components
    17:07:14.188 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000
    ....
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time: 14.409s
    Final Memory: 14M/643M
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem is that no coverage information is displayed in server. All data is displayed and updated afeter every execution, but coverage is not displayed. Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in your dump

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `../coverage-reports': File exists
```

Try removing `../coverage-reports` before running it again.

Comment: No, this is not the reason. coverage-reports is created by a bash script and complains because it exists, but the process continues. I doble-checked it. What bothers me is why sonar is parsing coverage generated files but not including them in reports

Comment: there might be a switch you need to pass perhaps to save the files?

Comment: @Killrazor `mkdir -p` for this particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

PythonCoverageSensor is picky about upper/lowercase names in the path.
See http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/Python-coverage-information-not-showing-up-in-Sonar-td5005729.html

So, if you do a "sonar-runner -X" to check the debug output from the runner in your project directory, where "sonar-project.properties" is located, you will find what the mixup in the path is doing.

"sonar-runner -X" is quite useful for all such tweaking and investigating what happens when Jenkins CI is running Sonar ...

Cheers!
;-)